# Connect to Kubernetes cluster without using gcloud sdk

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, azure-devops, kubectl

I´m new to kubernetes an created a cluster on google cloud platform.
Now i´m trying to setup automated deployment from vsts an need to create a kubernetes user for this to get a kubeconfig file for authentication.

Now my question is how can i do this?
Do i need to create this user with kubectl (if yes how?)?
Or is there a way to create the user through gcp console?

I searched the web but found nothing that worked. Thanks for any suggestions!

**Edit:**
I now how to connect to my cluster using this gcloud command: `gcloud container clusters get-credentials`. This work perfectly fine on my local dev machine.
But on my vsts build agent i dont have gcloud installed (and also dont want to install it) and need to use only kubectl to connect to my cluster without the gcloud command.

I have already figured out that the gcloud command creates a kubeconfig file with the gcloud command as auth provider (so i cant just copy the created kubeconifg file casue it depends on gcloud installed). When i then run kubectl it creates an temporary access token in the kubeconfig. But this token is only valid for about 30 minutes.
I need a token that is valid infinitely, so i can use this on my build server.

Answer (score 1):

To connect to Kubernetes cluster in GCP, you can use either user or service account.

If you choose user account, run this command:

```
gcloud init
```

or

```
gcloud init --console-only
```

This will bring up GCP authentication dialog. When you pass authentication, you'll be able to operate with permission of the authenticated user.

If you choose service account, you need to create it and generate a new key for it.

You can do it using *GPC console* -> *IAM & admin* -> *IAM* -> *Service accounts*.
Click on `Create service account`, select name for the account, select the appropriate role, and click `Create`.
You can generate the key by selecting `Furnish a new private key` in the account creation dialog box, or generate a new key by clicking on three dots on the right side of existed service account row and selecting `Create key`. Select JSON format and save the file on disk.

Then run the command:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account <service@account.name>  --key-file=<previously_saved_file.json>
```

At this stage, you are authenticated with CGP and ready to connect to your Kubernetes cluster:

Next command will update your kubectl configuration to work with your cluster.

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster_name> --zone <gcp_availability_zone> --project <gcp_project_name>
```

You can extend or decrease the account's permissions by selecting another role for it in GCP IAM management interface.

Official documentation:
[gcloud auth activate-service-account](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account)
[gcloud init](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/init)
[gcloud container clusters get-credentials](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials)

Comment: yeah, this i have already figured out.
My problem is, that i want to connect to my cluster WITHOUT the use of the `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` command. This command creates the kubeconifg with gcloud as auth provider, but i need a access token that i can use in my vsts build.

Comment: In this case its better to use kubernetes cluster authentification. I can suggest x509 certificate authentication as simple and secure solution. For GKE it could be more suitable to use service-account authentication. Take a look at the examples in authentication related Kubernetes documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**

Create a RoleBinding or a ClusterRoleBinding (depending on your needs) where the `subjects:` include an object of `kind: User` and `name: username`:

```
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: cluster-admin-users
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: starseed
```

**Explanation:**

This explanation assumes you are talking about a cluster with RBAC enabled, which should pretty much always be the case if you're on a recent version.

It's easy to be confused by this topic. Users and Groups exist only within the context of RoleBindings and ClusterRoleBindings as "subjects" as seen above.

The above code is a YAML object on which you could perform `kubectl apply -f thisfile.yml`. It would create a CluserRoleBinding which would bind the "user" (which is really just a string) starseed to the ClusterRole called "cluster-admin". "cluster-admin" is one of the default ClusterRoles. ClusterRoles (and Roles) are collections of API permissions, as described here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/#default-roles-and-role-bindings

There is no creation or deletion of users or groups - there are no API objects for a user or a group, and there is no way to list all users or all groups.

To understand why this is, there's a fundamental concept that you must wrap your head around - authentication and authorisation are *completely separate concerns* in kubernetes. Authentication deals with verifying "this user is who they say they are". As described here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/ - there are many valid methods of authentication. Common ones include tokens, username/password, x509 client certificates, but there are more. If a user presents a username and password that's present in the kube-apiserver's `--basic-auth=somefile.csv` flag, the kube-apiserver knows you're that user. If you use an x509 client certificate where the CommonName=starseed, and that cert is signed by a CA that kube-apiserver trusts, it knows you are that user.

At that point, when you try to make an API call like `kubectl get pods`, the kube-apiserver checks which *authorisation* methods are enabled (Node,RBAC is common). It'll find that the subject of a ClusterRoleBinding called cluster-admin-users is the user "starseed" and that therefore starseed can do anything the associated ClusterRole allows.

Comment: But how do I get an token for authentication?
I´m really confused with all this kubectl authentication stuff.

If i use the gcloud command `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` command it creates an token in my local kubeconfig file, but this token expires.

Comment: @dczychon unfortunately I don't know the answer to that with GKE. The way I know how to do it is unlikely to be right in an environment where you have no direct access to the control plane. Sorry!